# Scheme: sort elements by pivot

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm new to Scheme and to functional programming so please be gentle.
I'm trying to implement a function that takes a list and a pivot and return a list that contains the following 2 lists:

One for all elements that are less or equal to the pivot,

and one for all the elements that are greater than the pivot.

So I wrote the following code (EDITED (& WORKING) CODE - PROBLEM SOLVED):

```
define helper (lambda (lst pivot)
             (define lst1 null)
             (define lst2 null)
             (define my-split (lambda (lst pivot lst1 lst2)
                                 (if (null? lst)
                                     (list lst1 lst2)
                                     (if (<= (car lst) pivot)
                                         (my-split (cdr lst) pivot (cons (car lst) lst1) lst2)                                         
                                         (my-split (cdr lst) pivot lst1 (cons (car lst) lst2))))))                                   
              (my-split lst pivot lst1 lst2)))
```

My current problem is that `lst1` and `lst2` are `null` at the end of the run so I guess the problem is with the lines `(cons (car lst) lst1)` & `(cons (car lst) lst2)))`.

I saw some implementations on the web which use some complex commands that I'm not allowed to use (yes, it's homework).

Please offer ways to fix my code rather than offering your own.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly identified the two lines that are the main problem. `cons` just builds and returns a new list, whereas you're trying to mutate the variables `lst1` and `lst2`. The correct way to do this is `(set! lst1 (cons (car lst) lst1))` and `(set! lst2 (cons (car lst) lst2))`. Keep in mind, though, that good functional programming style avoids mutation. A good way to do that in this case would be to pass the two sub-lists as arguments as you recur down the main list, then return them when you get to the end.

Comment: Thank you for answering but as I mentioned, Im not allowed to use `set!`, I tried to add `lst1` & `lst2` to the input parameters and then pass them as arguments but the result is the same (see my edit). Can you provide a code sample of what you are offering?

Comment: @Noam You're almost there. Move the `(list lst1 lst2)` from the last line to the first arm of the first `if` expression (replacing `null`).

Comment: Thank you, SOLVED.

Comment: @Noam You're welcome. If you're having any trouble understanding the solution, let me know.

Comment: haha actually, I'm trying to take this `split` function and implement a full quick-sort algorithm, I had some trouble there so I opened a different post about it, if you're free, I would appreciate your help there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474008/scheme-implementing-a-quick-sort

Answer (score 1):

Just like an expression like `str.concat("hey")` in Java doesn't change what `str` is `(cons 1 lst1)` doesn't change what `lst1` is. It just returns a new value. Most of your function consist of dead code and if you really want to learn functional programming then altering bindings and objects are off limits.

You need to do something like this:

```
(define (count-odds lst)
  (define (helper lst odds)
    (cond ((null? lst) 
           odds)
          ((odd? (car lst)) 
           (helper (cdr lst) (+ 1 odds)))
          (else 
           (helper (cdr lst) odds))))    
  (helper lst 0))

(count-odds '(1 2 3))
; ==> 2
```

We never alter `odds`, we just update what is sent to the next recursion. Since Scheme has tail call elimination this is just like updating the variable in a while loop without actual mutation.

Comment: thank you for explaining, I understand your example, however I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem, I've edited my code, trying to do what you said but the result is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: When `split-at` returns `lst1` and `lst2` ends up at null values again. You would want to remove that since you want the result from `split-at` as the result. you also might want to do something with `lst1` and `lst2` when you hit the end of `lst` rather than returning null. Also `lst1` and `lst2` defined in the procedure has **nothing** to do with the parameters. They just happen to have the same name.